# sinatra "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra

I am trying to run an sinatra app. But the only page I am getting is "This is not the page you're looking for." Maybe I am not doing the URL right. Any help would be great.

http://localhost:9292/

**service.rb file**

```
  public
    helpers do
        def serialize(data, format)
            if format.upcase == "XML"
                classname = data.class.name.split('::').last.downcase
                if classname.upcase == "ARRAY"
                    classname = data.first.class.name.split('::').last.downcase
                    data.to_xml(:root_name => classname, :array_root_name => classname + "s")
                else
                    data.to_xml(:root_name => classname)
                end
            elsif format.upcase == "JSON"
                data.to_json
            else
                classname = data.class.name.split('::').last.downcase
            end
        end
    end
```

**Config.ru file**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require './service'
   require 'pry'


    root_dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)

   set :environment, :production
    set :root, root_dir
    set :app_file, File.join(root_dir, './service.rb')


      FileUtils.mkdir_p 'log' unless File.exists?('log')
        log = File.new("log/sinatra.log", "a")
      $stdout.reopen(log)

     DB = Sequel.connect(
:adapter => 'mysql',
:host => 'localhost',
:database => 'database',
:user => 'user',
:password => 'password')
   IllyriadApi::Service.setDatabase(DB)

  def app
IllyriadApi::Service
  end

  map '/' do
run IllyriadApi::Service
 end
```

C:\Users\dakota\Desktop\IllyriadAp>rackup config.ru

[2016-01-06 12:06:24] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1

[2016-01-06 12:06:24] INFO  ruby 2.2.3 (2015-08-18) [i386-mingw32]

[2016-01-06 12:06:24] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=1196 port=9292

::1 - - [06/Jan/2016:12:06:33 -0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 40 0.1130

[Link to the full source of the code just in case](https://github.com/kodabear4511/IllyriadApi/tree/master)

**alliance database**
1 "id"  H? "ticker" Harmless? "name"    2010-02-25 "founded_at"  14:18:07   10 "founded_by_player_id"   14646 "capital_town_id"     43 "member_count"   8651950 "total_population" 0.000    "tax_rate" 2012-10-14 18:48:43 "tax_rate_last_changed_at"   2012-01-19 17:42:55 "capital_town_last_moved_at"

**alliance_roles database**

1 "id"      Founder "name"  1 [->]  "alliance_id" 1 "hierarchy_id"

**towns database**
1 "id"  2016-01-05 00:03:31 "data_timestamp"    1 "town_id" Stormont "name" 383 "location_x" -1815 "location_y" 2010-02-21  22:08:02 "founded_at"   1 "owner_id"    12941 "population"  1 "is_capital"  1 "is_alliance_capital"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a `get` to `/`, you need to define route

```
get '/' do
  'Hello world!'
end
```

Replace `hello world` with any code you need to run when you open page http://localhost:9292/

Comment: current get code  get %r{/towns/name/(.+).(xml|json)} do |name, format|
            t = Town.filter(:name => name)
            if t == nil
                not_found
            else
                serialize(t, format)
            end
        end

Comment: That won't work. That route only responds when you make a get request to `/towns/name/x.json` for example.